# Why are Indian states divided based on the native language spoken?

Tags: india, language

All the Indian states are divided on the basis of language the native people speak such that each state has a native language which is not well spoken in other states.

Is this kind of  division followed only in India or are there other countries which are divided on the basis of language?

Comment: Mani, this needs a book to answer :) But I'll try later after looking up some references.

Comment: Difficult to tell what you are asking. What research have you done?

Comment: Belgium is divided like this too. As is Canada.

Comment: Agree with Mark. Could you update your question with more context so we can help you?

Comment: And so is the EU :)

Comment: @Drux The EU isn't a country (yet)

Comment: This is also largely true of Switzerland, with French speakers mostly living in their "own" jurisdictions, etc.